# Unset data from WordPress API (wp-json)

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I can already unset (remove specifics from normal posts) in the json returned from the WordPress API.  I actually use the following below from this example: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-wp-api-to-fetch-posts/

What I am having trouble with and can't figure out, is how to change this so it unsets data from a **Custom Post Type**

Thoughts?

```
function qod_remove_extra_data( $data, $post, $context ) {
  // We only want to modify the 'view' context, for reading posts
  if ( $context !== 'view' || is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
    return $data;
  }

  // Here, we unset any data we don't want to see on the front end:
  unset( $data['author'] );
  unset( $data['status'] );
  unset( $data['featured_image'] );
  //etc etc

  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'json_prepare_post', 'qod_remove_extra_data', 12, 3 );
```

custom post type example filter:

```
function projectPost_remove_extra_data( $data, $post, $context ) {

  if ( $context !== 'view' || is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
    return $data;
  }

  // Here, we unset any data we don't want to see on the front end:
  unset( $data['author'] );



  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'json_prepare_project', 'projectPost_remove_extra_data', 12, 3 );
```

Comment: Which API version are you using? It is changing for v2. Please see: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1195

Comment: @brainlmeritt   I am using version 1

Answer (score 4):

For wp-api v1.x, you need to extend `WP_JSON_CustomPostType`. There is an example in the pages file (`class-wp-json-pages.php`)

```
<?php
/**
 * Page post type handlers
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage JSON API
 */

/**
 * Page post type handlers
 *
 * This class serves as a small addition on top of the basic post handlers to
 * add small functionality on top of the existing API.
 *
 * In addition, this class serves as a sample implementation of building on top
 * of the existing APIs for custom post types.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage JSON API
 */
class WP_JSON_Pages extends WP_JSON_CustomPostType {
    /**
     * Base route
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $base = '/pages';

    /**
     * Post type
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type = 'page';

    /**
     * Register the page-related routes
     *
     * @param array $routes Existing routes
     * @return array Modified routes
     */
    public function register_routes( $routes ) {
        $routes = parent::register_routes( $routes );
        $routes = parent::register_revision_routes( $routes );
        $routes = parent::register_comment_routes( $routes );

        // Add post-by-path routes
        $routes[ $this->base . '/(?P<path>.+)'] = array(
            array( array( $this, 'get_post_by_path' ),    WP_JSON_Server::READABLE ),
            array( array( $this, 'edit_post_by_path' ),   WP_JSON_Server::EDITABLE | WP_JSON_Server::ACCEPT_JSON ),
            array( array( $this, 'delete_post_by_path' ), WP_JSON_Server::DELETABLE ),
        );

        return $routes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a page by path name
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $context
     *
     * @return array|WP_Error
     */
    public function get_post_by_path( $path, $context = 'view' ) {
        $post = get_page_by_path( $path, ARRAY_A );

        if ( empty( $post ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'json_post_invalid_id', __( 'Invalid post ID.' ), array( 'status' => 404 ) );
        }

        return $this->get_post( $post['ID'], $context );
    }

    /**
     * Edit a page by path name
     *
     * @param $path
     * @param $data
     * @param array $_headers
     *
     * @return true|WP_Error
     */
    public function edit_post_by_path( $path, $data, $_headers = array() ) {
        $post = get_page_by_path( $path, ARRAY_A );

        if ( empty( $post ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'json_post_invalid_id', __( 'Invalid post ID.' ), array( 'status' => 404 ) );
        }

        return $this->edit_post( $post['ID'], $data, $_headers );
    }

    /**
     * Delete a page by path name
     *
     * @param $path
     * @param bool $force
     *
     * @return true|WP_Error
     */
    public function delete_post_by_path( $path, $force = false ) {
        $post = get_page_by_path( $path, ARRAY_A );

        if ( empty( $post ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'json_post_invalid_id', __( 'Invalid post ID.' ), array( 'status' => 404 ) );
        }

        return $this->delete_post( $post['ID'], $force );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare post data
     *
     * @param array $post The unprepared post data
     * @param string $context The context for the prepared post. (view|view-revision|edit|embed|single-parent)
     * @return array The prepared post data
     */
    protected function prepare_post( $post, $context = 'view' ) {
        $_post = parent::prepare_post( $post, $context );

        // Override entity meta keys with the correct links
        $_post['meta']['links']['self'] = json_url( $this->base . '/' . get_page_uri( $post['ID'] ) );

        if ( ! empty( $post['post_parent'] ) ) {
            $_post['meta']['links']['up'] = json_url( $this->base . '/' . get_page_uri( (int) $post['post_parent'] ) );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'json_prepare_page', $_post, $post, $context );
    }
}
```

Replace "Pages" with "MyCustomPostTypes" and page with "mycustomposttype". Just be careful not to rename internal WordPress code that also uses the term `page`

Note: probably best to add this as a plugin rather than change the JSON-WP-API plugin

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyCustom JSON App API
 * Description: MyCustomPost handler for the JSON API
 * Dependency:  This plugin requires JSON-WP-API Plugin!!!! 
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * Version: 
 * Plugin URI: 
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

If possible, only the examples shown in internet is:

```
function qod_remove_extra_data ($ data, $ post, $ context) {
    // We only want to modify the 'view' context, for reading posts 
    if ($ context! == 'view' || is_wp_error ($ data)) {
        return $ data; 
    } 
    // Here, we unset any data we do not want to see on the front end: 
    unset ($data ['author']); 
    unset ($data ['status']); 
    // Continue unsetting whatever other fields you want return $ data;
}
add_filter ('json_prepare_post' 'qod remove extra_data', 12, 3);
```

**and right is:**

```
qod_remove_extra_data function ($ data, $ post, $ context) {
    // We only want to modify the 'view' context, for reading posts 
    if ($ context! == 'view' || is_wp_error ($ data)) {
         unset ( $data->data ['excerpt']); //Example
         unset ($data->data ['content']); //Example
         unset ($data->data ['name field to remove']) 
         //or 
         unset ($data->data ['name field to remove'] ['name subfield if you only want to delete the sub-field of field' ]) 
         return $data; 
     }
}
add_filter ('rest_prepare_post' 'qod_remove_extra_data', 12, 3);
```

IMPORTANT:
Is:
add_filter ('**rest_prepare_post**' 'qod_remove_extra_data', 12, 3);

Not:
add_filter ('**json_prepare_post**' 'qod remove extra_data', 12, 3); //WRONG

If is Custom Post Type:
add_filter ('**rest_prepare_{$post_type}**' 'qod_remove_extra_data', 12, 3);

EXAMPLE: Name post type = product;
add_filter ('**rest_prepare_product**' 'qod_remove_extra_data', 12, 3);

With this code can remove the fields that you want the JSON. By using rest_prepare} _ {$ post_type decide that you eliminated every post_type fields, thus only affected the post_type you want and not all.

Answer (score 1):

It should be no different to remove data from custom post types than from the built-in post types. Have you confirmed that your API call is actually returning your CPTs? First, you should look at the value of what is returned from: `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/posts/types`. Assuming that your CPT type shows up there, you should be able to query for items of that type, e.g. `product`, by calling: `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/posts?type=product`.

In other words, you should **not** change the name of the filter: you still want to tie into `json_prepare_post`. If you want to make your filter sensitive to post type and only remove certain fields if you have a CPT you could do something like:

```
function my_remove_extra_product_data( $data, $post, $context ) {
    // make sure you've got the right custom post type
    if ( 'product' !== $data[ 'type' ] ) {
        return $data;
    }
    // now proceed as you saw in the other examples
    if ( $context !== 'view' || is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
        return $data;
    }
    // unset unwanted fields
    unset( $data[ 'author' ] );

    // finally, return the filtered data
    return $data;
}

// make sure you use the SAME filter hook as for regular posts
add_filter( 'json_prepare_post', 'my_remove_extra_product_data', 12, 3 );
```

You can find more documentation in the [WP API Getting Started Guide](http://wp-api.org/guides/getting-started.html#getting-posts).

Comment: I updated my working example to what you listed, and it wasn't able to unset any of the data.  The api is working, and I actually hit it with an ajax call to get the title, acf field and content area.

Comment: could you provide a link to your site?

Comment: ah, okay, that sounds good. Inside the function, as the first line, add the following: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($data) . '</pre>'; exit;` and run it again. This should do a var dump of the `$data` variable. It's very possible that either we're trying to unset variables that don't exist, or that we're trying to access object members as array indices.

Comment: just added it, it looks like its the 2nd option. Also when  I added that, the posts unset variables are now added back

Comment: okay, so the line I asked you to add was just for debugging. take that out. try doing something like `unset($data->author)` instead of `unset($data['author'])`

Comment: the bottom line is that 1) we know we've got the correct filter, i.e. `json_prepare_post`, and 2) the properties we want to set are indeed present and available to be unset. we just needed to know how to get rid of them.

Comment: That didn't do anything unfortunately.  When I comment out the "if" project statement, then unset works again for posts

Comment: yeah, it should be `if ( 'project' !== $data->type ) {}`. I think you need this or it will unset fields in ALL post types and not just projects.